# Lowest 5% of offers Question?

Tags: statistics

Mr. Clark offers an apartment for $430. Do you think his price is within the lowest 5% of offers?

Provide a clear answer and complete mathematical reasoning.

Workings:

I am reviewing for Statistics final and I don't know where to even start for this problem so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is silly.  Absent context how could this possibly be answered?

Comment: I know! That is what I am thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess the intended answer (not that I think it a good one) is that because you know nothing about the distribution of offers you can be $95\%$ confident that his offer is not in the lowest $5\%$.  Of course, if you know nothing about the distribution of offers there may be only five of them and there are none in the bottom $5\%$.

Comment: That is honestly the best answer I think there can be for this problem. Thank you!